# Escrever num LCD display 2x16 com o MCU 8051 IDE em liguagem c

Tags: c, microcontrolador-8051

Queria escrever umas palavras num LCD Display 2x16, já tenho o código que vou expor aqui, mas não sei porque isto da-me um erro:

> HD44780 ERROR: Neither 'Set DDRAM ADDRESS' nor ''Set CGRAM ADDRESS'
>   instruction was issued prior to the write instruction.

Já me tem aparecido em outros projectos e eu não sei o que significa nem o que posso ter mal. 
Aqui está o meu código:

```
#include "sdcc_reg420.h"
#define LCD_PORT P1
#define En P3_5
#define RS P3_1
#define RW P3_0

void LCD_comando(unsigned char comando);
void LCD_init (void);
void LCD_date(char letra);
//void inicio ();

void LCD_init (void)            //inicialização do LCD
{
    LCD_comando(0b00111000);    //duas linhas e caracteres 5x7
    LCD_comando(0b00001111);    //cursor ON,DisplayON, Piscar ON
    LCD_comando(0b00000001);    //Limpar o LCD
    LCD_comando(0b00000110);    //modo de entrada de dados: em incremento e Shift total off
    LCD_comando(0b10000000);    //modo de entrada de dados: endreço inicial da memoria DDRAM
}

void LCD_comando(unsigned char comando)
{
  LCD_PORT=comando;
  RS=0;
  RW=0;
  En=0;
  En=1;
}


void LCD_date(char letra)
{
  LCD_PORT=letra;
  RS=1;
  RW=0;
  //En=0;
  En=1;
}


void main (void)
{
  LCD_date(' ');
  LCD_date(' ');
  LCD_date('B');
  LCD_date('O');
  LCD_date('M');
  LCD_date('B');
  LCD_date('A');
  LCD_date('S');
  LCD_date('T');
  LCD_date('I');
  LCD_date('C');
  LCD_date('O');
  LCD_date(' ');
  LCD_date(' ');
  LCD_date(' ');
  LCD_date(0);
  LCD_comando(0b11000000);
  LCD_date(' ');
  LCD_date(' ');
  LCD_date('A');
  LCD_date('N');
  LCD_date('A');
  LCD_date(' ');
  LCD_date('C');
  LCD_date(' ');
  LCD_date('M');
  LCD_date('A');
  LCD_date(' ');
  LCD_date(' ');
}
```

A IDE que estou a usar é a MCU 8051, agradecia a vossa ajuda.

Comment: Aqui esta o novo codigo:

Comment: Entre nesta sala:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19749/discussao-mutley-e-ana-costa

Comment: Você poderia me dizer qual compilador está usando? Se você estiver usando o avr-gcc, acho que eu posso lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

O erro significa que não tem uma memória onde será escrito o texto, logo não tem como escrever texto algum.

Pode ser porque a função de inicialização não é executada antes das outras.

## EDIT

Pelo que infiro a partir do código, `RS` e `RW` são registradores que indicam se tem algo a ser lido ou escrito, respectivamente.

No caso do `LCD_comando`, ambos estão recebendo 0, indicando que não tem nada a ser lido ou escrito, porém no `LCD_date` apenas o `RS`, que é o que indica algo para ler, que está recebendo `1`, então de todo modo, o LCD está apenas lendo caracteres.

Comment: obrigada, realmente o erro desapareceu, mas continua sem escrever para o LCD vou colocar de aqui o codigo novo para ver se me consegue ajudar!